# Pass an array of tag parameters to the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I want to retrieve top tagged questions per day using the Stack Exchange API.

This API call works for "oracle":

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?inname=oracle&site=stackoverflow

Now I want to pass an array of parameters to this API in a single call.

I want to get the number of questions posted per tag.

Can I pass an array of tags to the API?

Comment: An array of *what* parameters, for what purpose?  Some API routes allow arrays, some don't.  More importantly, forget about "how"; what is the desired end result?

Comment: I want to ger the number of questions posted per tag. If the parameter is  an array the i can pass all the tags in one call..hope its clear

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear.  Many API routes do allow arrays for inputs where such would make sense and is not too "expensive".

The [plain `/tags` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) does not take arrays in its main parameter (`inname`) because `inname` performs a wildcard-ish search, and mixing the two would be too "costly", server-side.

But you can send an array of tags to [**the `/tags/{tags}/info` route**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name).

For example to get the number of questions for the `oracle`, `mysql`, and `sql-server` tags you could call:

[/2.2/tags/oracle;mysql;sql-server/info?site=stackoverflow&filter=!bNKX0pggz90UuM](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#order=desc&sort=popular&tags=oracle%3Bmysql%3Bsql-server&filter=!bNKX0pggz90UuM&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

which returns:

```
{
  "count": 514139,
  "name": "mysql"
}, {
  "count": 229607,
  "name": "sql-server"
}, {
  "count": 96037,
  "name": "oracle"
}
```

---

**Important:**

1. Almost all array parameters to the API are separated by semicolons (`;`)
2. Although you should be able to pass up to 100 tags in at a time, [**there is currently a bug that limits this.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309002/the-api-crashes-when-trying-to-retrieve-multiple-tags)  To be safe, pass in no more than 45 tags at a time for now.

Comment: I do not understand having a bug on searching more than  45 tags in a call !! May be i am missing something

Comment: Elaborate on what's unclear.  The API does not function as it should. Until they fix it, [if the `tags` parameter exceeds 909 characters, the API instance will crash instead of responding properly to your request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309002/the-api-crashes-when-trying-to-retrieve-multiple-tags).  To avoid that, I suggested not requesting more the 45 tags at a time.  That number is a bit of a SWAG for convenience/ease-of-implementation. It's really the total parameter length that triggers the bug.